# Large dataset mapping into a table

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

My question has 2 sub-questions:

1. Let's assume a case where every second I receive data which is represented as a set of key/value tuples. Each value is basically a 64bit counter. I need to save it into a database. The number of values is several thousands. Out of those thousands only 1% has actual data, others are null (sparsely populated set). Does it make sense to make a table of few thousand columns? Or just store as "id, timestamp, key, value"?
2. In case the answer to question 1 is "thousands of columns", which da from mysql/postgres family should be used?

The read pattern for this case is mostly charting, so select will be a bunch of data based on timestamps. So it is uniform 1/sec writes and occasional reads of all data or data in date/time range.

Bonus question, what pattern can be used to store such data in NoSQL database? For example in MongoDB a collection of stats containing documents with just 1% of the whole set can be used. How would it work with read/map/reduce in that case? How would reading the data compare with mysql/postgres?

Edit: My usecase is very similar to NewRelic service but instead of having lots of small datasets I have much larger datasets (sparsely populated out of even bigger set) but less often (and fewer users)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL stores null columns as a bitmap, however there is a large overhead per each row. Lets calculate the storage efficiency of the two storage schemes:

```
Average row length for wide table with thousands of columns:
23 bytes row header + 1000*1bit + average 2 bytes of alignment + 4 bytes id
   + 8 bytes timestamp + 10*8 bytes values = 242 bytes

Average number of bytes for storing each value separately:
10 values * (23 bytes row header + 1 byte alignment + 4 bytes id
   + 8 bytes timestamp + 4 bytes key + 8 bytes value) = 480 bytes
```

So thousand columns is about twice as efficient as splitting it out by key. The crossover point where it would be more efficient to store keys separately is at [about 0.45%](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281000%2ap%2a%2823%2B1%2B8%2B4%2B8%29%29%2F%2823%2B1000%2F8+%2B+2+%2B+4+%2B+8+%2B+1000%2ap%2a8%29%3D1).

This approach won't scale very far however. The maximum number of columns in PostgreSQL is limited to 1600. To extend it further you could split the values vertically into many tables. This will also have some issues querying, because a result set can't be much larger than 1600 either.

Another option is to encode the key value pairs into arrays. The structure of the table in this case would be (id serial, ts timestamptz, keys int2[], values int8[]). The storage overhead for the same 1000 attributes, 1% fill factor would be:

```
23 bytes row header + 1 byte alignment + 4 bytes id + 8 bytes timestamp
   + 20 bytes array header + 10*2 byte values + 20 bytes array header
   + 10*8 byte values = 176 bytes per entry
```

However querying singular values requires slightly more infrastructure in this case.

If even better storage efficiency or flexibility is needed, a custom datatype can be added.

I know that the large number columns pattern for sensor data is used successfully in many PostgreSQL installations. As for database choice, I may be slightly biased, but I would suggest PostgreSQL, because you'll have much better tools like arrays, predicate indexes and custom datatypes to rearrange your data storage for more efficiency. Most important thing to keep in mind is to use partitioning from the get go.

Comment: Just be aware that "thousands" of columns is approaching PostgreSQL's limit for supported row size; see http://www.postgresql.org/about/ . Don't rely on being able to just keep on adding columns. I'd strongly recommend using arrays.

Comment: I see, as per Postgresqlm manual: "Maximum Columns per Table 250 - 1600 depending on column types" -thanks.

Comment: Good point about this not scaling very far. The hard limit is set at exactly 1600, and can't be grown without changing the page layout that PostgreSQL uses. I'll amend the answer with an array based sparse encoding.

Answer (score 0):

The only case when you need to design a table with thousands of same datatype columns is, your database has other tables that need to have foreign key constaints with these columns. Other than that having thousands of columns is, at best, unmanageable.

You can also use a persistent map storage engine like [jdbm2](http://code.google.com/p/jdbm2/). It is designed for a similar use case like yours.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion on the subject but I don't see this answering the questions. Also JDBM2 does not seem to fit the bill: no concurrency, no indexes, no replication, etc.

Comment: He asked "does it make sense". And my answer is no.